# Python TypeError: function takes 1 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python, tkinter, arguments, typeerror

I have a function that is design to operate like `root.title(winTitle)`. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
class UIWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        Tk()
    def setWindowTitle(winTitle):
        self.title(winTitle)
```

But when I run it, it gives the error:

```
TypeError: setWindowTitle() takes one positional argument but two was given
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're missing the `self` with in the method so that it would be `def  setWindowTitle(self, winTitle)`

Comment: Please don't change the question to make the code work. When you do that, the question no longer applies.  If you believe the question will be helpful to future readers, post the answer in the answer section.  If you don't, delete the question.

Comment: @WozzyCoder I added self,but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not diagnostic.  Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Your second problem is that you aren't properly subclassing `Tk`.  Change `class UIWindow():` to `class UIWindow(Tk):`  Change `Tk()` to `Tk.__init__(self)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *
class UIWindow():
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        self.root=Tk(*arg, **kwarg)
    def setWindowTitle(self, winTitle):
        self.root.title(winTitle)

x = UIWindow()
x.setWindowTitle("This is the Test Title.")
x.root.mainloop()
```

You are missing **self**. This is the small example to show window with title.

Comment: Updated code , given you a sample code. This demonstrates to set the title. Query is always welcome :)

Comment: It works !! Thank you so much. But why is this happening. Can you show me ?